# How to create Error log for ejabberd messages

Tags: module, erlang, xmpp, ejabberd

I have ejabberd 15.07 and i need to create Error log that logs only message that are returned back as error to its originator. we have user_send_packet hook using which it is possible to log all the packets sent to server but how to filter the error messages from it?

When client sends a message,this message is first received at server where server parse this Xml packet to verify it syntactically, beside that perform  privacy and auth check also before routing it to it's receiver. if server finds any error or sender of this message lacks any authorization , it return this message back to sender and modify its type to error to inform him.
now what i need is to trace this message before routing back to it's sender.

Comment: I think you should clarify what you want to do and possibly show some code of what you have tried. I have hard time understanding what you want to do.

Comment: Sorry for the trouble you had to understand, As i am a  newbie to erlang and ejabberd. it's been difficult for me to explain sometime . i hope now onward i will have more clarify and explicit explanation . I am very thankful  to you .

Comment: Thanks Mickael for answering but You didn't get what i am asking for ?

Comment: Well, you asked how to create log messages. I could not understand more than that.

Answer (score 0):

Logging at error loglevel can be done using ?ERROR macro.

For example:

```
?ERROR_MSG("Error: ~p", [Err])
```

Note that you need to include `logger.hrl` at top of the module file:

```
-include("logger.hrl").
```